# Can I use Xlib in service?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, xlib, xorg

I am writing a C++ program that will run as a service in ubuntu. In it I need to use the Xlib library to manage the X session. But because I'm running the program as a systemd service, it doesn't have access to the X session.

I tried to get around this by assigning the variables $XAUTHORITY and $DISPLAY to my service's environment. But the thing is, there is no way I can get the $XAUTHORITY variable from the service. Since it contains the path to the X session authorization file, I tried to find the path myself by knowing the UID, but the authorization file is in different places in different systems.

Is there any other way to get around this limitation and access Xorg from the systemd service?

Comment: The first question you want ask yourself: what exactly do you really want to do. X sessions come and ago.  If someone were to log out, and their X session disappears altogether, what do you expect to happen to your service? What if there are multiple concurrent X sessions? What if there's one X session on the system console, and another X session in a VNC connection? What do you expect your service to do? Which X session does it pick and choose? Why? How do you expect it to work? How do you expect your service to know about new or removed X sessions, there's no developed API for that, at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have stated all that in the question. Through Xlib I need to find out what windows the current user has open at the moment, track mouse movements and do many other things with the display. I have code in my program that tracks the actual current user and it is his X session that I need to access. I have username and uid of current user. I know, when user logs in and logs out, so, i would like to get access to X session after user's login

Comment: That's something else, entirely. You asked a different question: how to find the X session from a systemd-launched service. The short answer: it won't work. This kind of an application is usually not done by a systemd-launched service, but a service that's native to the desktop environment (DE). Gnome, Kde, Xfce, et. al. define their own mechanisms for automatically launching processes in new X sessions, and they inherits the usual XAUTHORITY, DISPLAY, et. al. in their environment, naturally. Write your service as a regular daemon, and leave the job of launching it to the DE.